# 3D Touch Quick Action 4 Item Limit?

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, 3dtouch

My app is set up with Quick Actions for 3D Touch.  However, I noticed that I'm limited to only 4 items even when I try to add more.  I haven't successfully found any documentation confirming this.  Has anyone else found this limitation?

Thanks,
Hino

Answer (score 3):

Here you have quote from Apple documentation:

> iOS 9 displays up to four Home screen quick actions for your app. Within this limit, the system shows your static quick actions first, starting at the topmost position in the menu. If your static items do not exhaust the limit and you have also defined dynamic quick actions, then one or more of your dynamic quick actions is displayed.

doc link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/3DTouchAPIs.html